# SQL Inner Join 2 times

Tags: sql, oracle, join

I would like to verify if the SQL query I wrote is correct or can be improved based on the problem statement given below.

Table td contains items purchased by customer and the status of order. I would like to write a query to calculate additional
money that could have been earned if the customer had not returned items and the percentage increase
with respect to actual amount of money earned.

```
===== Table td =====
customer_id    qty    price_per_item($)  order_status
    1           3       2                 complete
    1           2       4                 cancelled
    2           2       3                 complete
    2           3       5                 complete
    3           5       2                 complete
    3           4       7                 cancelled
```

This is what I have written as SQL query, but I am not sure if it's correct. Please suggest if this query can be improved.

```
select Actual_money.customer_id , Lost_money.lost_money , Actual_money.actual_money,
 Total_money.total_money , 100.0 * Lost_money.lost_money  / Actual_money.actual_money As percentage_increase
from  
       (select td.customer_id, sum(td.qty * td.price_per_item) lost_money               
                    from td
                   where td.order_status in 'cancelled'
                    group by td.customer_id) Lost_money
        inner join            

       (select td.customer_id, sum(td.qty * td.price_per_item) actual_money            
               from td
              where td.order_status in 'complete'
               group by td.customer_id) Actual_money

               on Lost_money.customer_id= Actual_money.customer_id
       inner join

        (select td.customer_id, sum(td.qty * td.price_per_item) total_money           
               from td
                             group by td.customer_id) Total_money  

                    on Actual_money.customer_id = Total_money.customer_id ;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need for joins, much simpler is condititional sum:

```
select customer_id, lost_money, actual_money, total_money, 
       100.0 * lost_money  / total_money as percentage_increase
  from (select customer_id, sum(qty * price_per_item) total_money, 
               sum(case order_status when 'cancelled' then qty * price_per_item end) lost_money,
               sum(case order_status when 'complete'  then qty * price_per_item end) actual_money
          from td group by customer_id)
  where lost_money is not null
```

**<sup>[dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=dbf9e8589c86ecb6d84e756e70ae99eb)</sup>**

This way you scan table only once. Last line eliminates rows without cancelled orders, you can also use `having` clause to achieve this.  I changed formula a little to `lost/total`, this seems to be more informative, but you can stay at yours.

---

**Edit:**  Explain plan output for original query

```
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation             | Name | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT      |      |     2 |   156 |    10  (40)| 00:02:53 |
|*  1 |  HASH JOIN            |      |     2 |   156 |    10  (40)| 00:02:53 |
|*  2 |   HASH JOIN           |      |     2 |   104 |     7  (43)| 00:01:53 |
|   3 |    VIEW               |      |     2 |    52 |     3  (34)| 00:00:52 |
|   4 |     HASH GROUP BY     |      |     2 |    90 |     3  (34)| 00:00:52 |
|*  5 |      TABLE ACCESS FULL| TD   |     2 |    90 |     2   (0)| 00:00:35 |
|   6 |    VIEW               |      |     4 |   104 |     3  (34)| 00:00:52 |
|   7 |     HASH GROUP BY     |      |     4 |   180 |     3  (34)| 00:00:52 |
|*  8 |      TABLE ACCESS FULL| TD   |     4 |   180 |     2   (0)| 00:00:35 |
|   9 |   VIEW                |      |     6 |   156 |     3  (34)| 00:00:52 |
|  10 |    HASH GROUP BY      |      |     6 |   234 |     3  (34)| 00:00:52 |
|  11 |     TABLE ACCESS FULL | TD   |     6 |   234 |     2   (0)| 00:00:35 |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Proposed query:

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation           | Name | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT    |      |     6 |   270 |     3  (34)| 00:00:52 |
|*  1 |  FILTER             |      |       |       |            |          |
|   2 |   HASH GROUP BY     |      |     6 |   270 |     3  (34)| 00:00:52 |
|   3 |    TABLE ACCESS FULL| TD   |     6 |   270 |     2   (0)| 00:00:35 |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: . . You misunderstand aggregation, if you think the table is scanned only once.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Table is hit only once this way, not three times and joined, so isn't this query better?

Comment: . . and then it is written and read at least one more time (but typically more than that) to process the aggregation.

Comment: I added explain plans for both queries.